# how to remove index column from multi index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've seen a lot of answers on flattening multi-level index. I just want to remove the very first index column on the left of this multi-index dataframe.

**From this:**

```
Attributes       Date    Close    Close               
Symbols                   AMZN      ^DJI  
0          2020-12-01  3220.08  29823.92  
1          2020-11-30  3168.04  29638.64  
2          2020-11-27  3195.34  29910.37  
3          2020-11-25  3185.07  29872.47
```

**I'm looking for this outcome:**

```
       Date    Close    Close               
               AMZN      ^DJI  
2020-12-01  3220.08  29823.92  
2020-11-30  3168.04  29638.64  
2020-11-27  3195.34  29910.37  
2020-11-25  3185.07  29872.47
```

Is this possible?

Comment: if I export to CSV  -- df.to_csv("my_data.csv", index=False) -- I'm able to drop the index, but I'm not sure how to do it without exporting to csv.

Comment: index is fundamental to a dataframe and will always be there. However, you can do, `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` , but an index will still be there of 0,1,2,3,4, etc.

Comment: I thought so too, but your code is not dropping that attirbutes/symbols part.

Comment: This is what I get when I print(df.columns)
MultiIndex([(  'Date',     ''),
            ( 'Close', 'AMZN'),
            ( 'Close', '^DJI'),
            (  'High', 'AMZN'),
            (  'High', '^DJI'),
            (   'Low', 'AMZN'),
            (   'Low', '^DJI'),
            (  'Open', 'AMZN'),
            (  'Open', '^DJI'),
            ('Volume', 'AMZN'),
            ('Volume', '^DJI')],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])

Comment: You can rename it to `''` (blank) if that is what you mean: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.rename.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need set first MultiIndex column to index use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with rename index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) - so output is `DataFrame` with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index([('Date', '')]).rename_axis(index=None, columns=('Date',''))
print (df)
Date          Close          
               AMZN      ^DJI
2020-12-01  3220.08  29823.92
2020-11-30  3168.04  29638.64
2020-11-27  3195.34  29910.37
2020-11-25  3185.07  29872.47
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, I tried that but I get:     raise TypeError("Must pass list-like as `names`.")
TypeError: Must pass list-like as `names`.

Comment: @AdamSchroeder - My typo, sorry, need `columns=('Date','')`

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, this is easiest way to do it:

```py
df.reset_index().drop(columns="Attributes", axis = 1)
```